# C++ memory protect pointers

Tags: c++

Is it possible to "memory protect" pointers so that it's actually impossible to change them in the code, so that attempting to change them in the code results in a bus error? I am not referring to `const` but some type of deeper immutability assurance on the OS level. The question applies to any OS.

(Carmack mentions something like that here: https://youtu.be/Uooh0Y9fC_M?t=1h41m)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. But `const` allows you to decalre immutable things.

Comment: Why the downvote? How can I improve my question? I know about const, and that's not what I'm asking about, please see the video.

Comment: Make it such that what you're asking is clear and on-topic, without readers having to watch a video. See [ask].

Comment: What do you want to protect them from? Changes by subclasses? Changes by other (public) clients? Changes by external hacks that directly modify your memory? Changes by the magnetic field of the earth flipping bits?

Comment: @CompuChip Pretty sure he meant the magnetic field here.

Comment: Alright I have added more info, and tried to make it clear what I'm asking for, and changed the link to the video to be a side note. Please reconsider your downvotes, as well as telling me how to further improve my question.

Comment: You don't even mention which OS you need a solution for. And asking people to watch a video in order to understand a question is not very nice. If everyone did this... You should instead write a brief summary of the video contents.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I did write a summary of the relevant part of the video, it's the main portion of the post. The video is just optional extra information if someone were interested. The question is agnostic as to which OS the solution is applied to, which I thought would be understood from the fact that I did not ask about a specific OS.

Comment: But how can such a question be OS-agnostic? It's effectively asking how to go beyond the rules of C++, which give you only `const`.

Comment: That's a good point there Christian, I will add some information to my post in order to help anyone else who might also be confused by that.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is quite general, here are some general ideas.

From within your application, the language gives you a number of constructs to protect your data. For example, data that is not meant to be exposed should be flagged as `private`. This does not prevent clients from reverse engineering your class though, for example if you have

```
class C {
  public:  int a;
  private: int b;
};
```

then usually you will be able to access `b` through `int* pB = &(c.a) + 1`. This is not standard by any definition, but on *most* systems this will *probably* work. In general, because C++ allows very low-level memory management you can basically access *any* part of your applications memory from anywhere within the application, though making sensible (ab)use of this requires some reverse engineering.

When you expose public data, you can return `const` references and pointers, but of course it is very easy to still change this memory:

```
const* T myImmutable = new T();
const_cast<T*>(myImmutable)->change(); // Oops
```

Again, this is not standard C++ as compilers will use the `const` qualifier to perform optimizations, and things may break when you circumvent that, but the language does not stop you from doing this.

If you want to protect your memory from external changes, things become a bit trickier. In general, the OS makes sure that the memory assigned to different processes is separated and you cannot just go and write in the memory space of other processes. However, [there are some functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory) in the Windows API (`Read`/`WriteProcessMemory`) that one may use. Of course, this requires heavy reverse engineering to determine exactly *where* in memory the pointer to be changed is located, but it is possible. Some ways of protecting against this are VirtualProtect, as mentioned in [Dani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36100390/2920343). There are increasingly complex things that you can do, like keeping checksums of important data or

> [writing a] driver that monitors the SSDT and then catches when WriteProcessMemory or ReadProcessMemory is executed and you can squash those calls if they're pointed at the game

but as the first answer on the [page I found that on](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?504240-how-to-Protect-application-process-from-ReadProcessMemory-and-WriteProcessMemory) correctly points out:

> Safety doesn't exist. The only thing you can do is make it as hard as possible to crack

which is a lesson that you should never forget!